# Shenzen ios build giving error

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I'm getting the following error when running the Shenzen (https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen) utility.  I am using Xcode 6 beta 4 trying to build an ios app. Any thoughts?

```
ipa build 

Select a scheme:
1. FieldApp-LOCAL
2. FieldApp-RELEASE
?  2
     xcodebuild  FieldApp.xcworkspace
2014-07-28 09:00:43.703 xcodebuild[35326:1912070] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6244.6/IDEFoundation/SourceControl/Model/IDESourceControlManager.m:432
Details:  Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDESourceControlErrorDomain Code=-1 "Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion" UserInfo=0x7fb4a2cb14a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion}
Object:   <IDESourceControlManager: 0x7fb4a072c9e0>
Method:   -loadRepositories
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fb4a0605350>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    DataModelVersionCompile /Users/seanzehnder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FieldApp-heytvqitcxovbbegdtzbrxjofaty/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FieldApp-RELEASE/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Visit\ Tracker.app/FieldApp.momd DataModel/FieldApp.xcdatamodeld
    DataModelVersionCompile /Users/seanzehnder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FieldApp-heytvqitcxovbbegdtzbrxjofaty/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/FieldApp-RELEASE/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Visit\ Tracker.app/FieldApp.momd DataModel/FieldApp.xcdatamodeld
(2 failures)
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on the error? Did you google the error? Did you read the error properly?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887565/list-command-hangs-in-xcode

Answer (score 2):

First get it running and test it in XCode, then check the log for any errors.

Then you can try building it.

It may be that you haven't got the audio listener properly set up!

It could also be that you built it in xcode 4 so Xcode 6 would show lots of errors, Path errors etc. It is likely that there is a compatibility issue :)