# List command hangs in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Jenkins Xcode plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin) to build an iOS application, however it hangs when running the following command on a project I have inherited from another developer:

```
$ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list
```

It also hangs when I run this command manually from a terminal. Does anyone know what the cause may be? The warning displayed is also displayed on another project I have, but it does not hang in this case.

Running Xcode 6.1 on OS X 10.10

```
$ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -list
2014-11-12 04:47:21.234 xcodebuild[42642:1431240] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6604/IDEFoundation/SourceControl/Model/IDESourceControlManager.m:423
Details:  Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDESourceControlErrorDomain Code=-1 "Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion" UserInfo=0x7f9792309200 {NSLocalizedDescription=Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion}
Object:   <IDESourceControlManager: 0x7f9792302860>
Method:   -loadRepositories
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9790d2dbe0>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
Information about project "DOHSmokefree":
Targets:
    DOHSmokefree
    DOHSmokefreeTests

Build Configurations:
    Debug
    Release

If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue when updating to Xcode 6.1 while using a newer version of subversion on the command line.
Disabling Source Control in Xcode Preferences should do the trick.

If that isn't an option you might try replacing the subversion implementation inside Xcode as I have done, using this technique: [Use SVN 1.7 in XCode 4.3+](http://tgoode.com/2012/03/31/use-svn-1-7-in-xcode-4-3/)

Basically that would be the following steps:

This assumes you already have SVN 1.7 installed to /opt/subversion, you can get it from WANdisco: http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/download#osx

Now open the Terminal and get an elevated shell using `sudo -s`.

Then, cd to inside the XCode.app package, to where the SVN binaries are.

Make a backup directory and move the old SVN files into it

```
bash-3.2# mkdir bup
bash-3.2# mv svn* bup/
```

Lastly, symbolically link the new files into the package:

```
bash-3.2# ln -s /opt/subversion/bin/svn* ./
```

That’s it!

Comment: This solved my issue. I was able to disable source control in Xcode and the problem has now gone. I still get the "Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion" error, however the command no longer hangs. Thanks

Comment: it took me forever to find "where the SVN binaries are" - mine were at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/`

Answer (score 4):

TLDR; My solution: Mark the schemes as shared in XCode if building them from the command line as a different user, or without ever opening XCode on the build machine.

I was having this same problem, intermittently on our CI server.  I came across this question.  The accepted answer with the problem being an issue and fixing the SVN version did not work for me as the SVN being used on the CI server was the default SVN and it was, as mentioned, working intermittently.

What I finally noticed is that, between a working version and a non-working version the schemes were not being listed.  I had recently upgraded a library on the project and that got me to thinking about the schemes.  After realizing that schemes are stored locally per user, unless shared, the fix for me was to go into the scheme manager and mark the schemes as shared.

The problem apparently being that the CI server user never actually opened the project in Xcode, thus causing the list command to hang because there were no available schemes for the user to build.

The times when it had intermittently worked were times after, logged in as the CI server user, I had opened the project in Xcode to test the build process, thus creating the necessary schemes. Wiping the CI server or refactoring/adding schemes would cause the build to break until the project was reopened in Xcode in desperation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on OS X 10.10 with XCode 6.4，just close XCode's Source Control to solved this issue:

1. run XCode
2. open Menu: XCode -> Preferences...
3. Click "Source Control" Tab and uncheck "Enable Source Control"